# rabbitmq setting requeue in spring xd

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-xd

1) spring-xd rabbitmq 'requeue=false' option not working.

 below both setting result is same.
i was set 'requeue' option to 'false' but rabbitmq always attempt requeue(=retry).

Are there any priorities between these options?

Is the (maxAttempts priority > requeue priority)???

```
module.*.consumer.requeue = true
module.*.consumer.maxAttempts = 5


module.*.consumer.requeue = false
module.*.consumer.maxAttempts = 5
```

---

2) how to auto processing DLQ back to the bus queue?
( using the spring xd setting...)

---

3) Is there another way to ask the second question?

---

please help me :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requeue option only makes sense when retry is turned off (maxAttempts=1).

When retry is enabled (maxAttempts > 1), the message is rejected and not requeued after the retries are exhausted.

Turn on DEBUG logging to see the retry and message rejection behavior.

There is no mechanism provided to move messages back to the main queue - see [this documentation for the newer Spring Cloud Stream project](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/pull/12/files) for some suggestions.